# What is the potential variation inside solid conducting sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conductors

The information on the internet is highly unreliable, these websites say that potential remains constant inside conducting solid sphere:

> [Electric potential inside a conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175760/)
>
> http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potsph.html

These sites say potential varies as a function of distance:

> [Integration for finding potential inside uniformly charged solid sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308744/)
>
> http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl94.pdf

which one is it?

Comment: Welcome to the internet! The sphere in second case is non-conducting.

Comment: This is a homework-like question. So please tell us, what your reasoning. What do you thin and why?

Comment: @samjoe but it does say conducting!

Comment: -1. @verynewuser Where is it written that the uniformly charged solid sphere is a conductor? These are two different problems.

Comment: @sammygerbil sorry for asking questions on the internet. "What may be obvious to one may not be to other" but that certainly doesn't apply everywhere does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, notice that the sphere is uniformly charged i.e. there is a volume charge present in the medium. But in conductors that certainly cannot be the case. All charges must reside on the outer surface of a conductor. So this is not about a conductor. Potential inside a conductor is unambiguously constant.

To prove that you must understand that electric field inside a conductor is zero. (By inside I mean, in the meat of the conductor, where there is material, not in some cavity.) So, if there was a varying potential inside the conductor, then there would have been a change in potential with distance, creating a gradient in the potential. Now the negative gradient of potential is nothing but electric field, which turns out to be non-zero in case of varying potential. But as mentioned previously, electric field inside a conductor is zero. So our initial assumption must be false. i.e. potential inside a conductor cannot vary.

For further reading study Electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths.

Comment: never ever had someone explained something complex so easily thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second case is *charged*, but not conductive.

If it were conductive, the repulsion between the charges would keep it from remaining uniformly charged. All of the charge would move to the outer surface of the sphere.

Comment: But http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potsph.html says "charged". is there something else

Comment: Yes, but on a charged conducting sphere, the charge will be on the outer surface. It will not be distributed uniformly through the sphere.